# wagtail-menus is loading the menu but not my page links

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

It was working before I deleted and recreated my database, I have no idea why it's no longer working, I've ensured that show in menus is checked under the promote panel.

***base.html***

```html
{% load static wagtailuserbar %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{% load menu_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" content="text/html">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>
    {% block title %}
    {% if self.seo_title %}{{ self.seo_title }}{% else %}{{ self.title }}{% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block title_suffix %}
    {% with self.get_site.site_name as site_name %}
    {% if site_name %}- {{ site_name }}{% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endblock %}
  </title>
  <meta name="description" content="text/html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />



  {% block extra_css %}
  {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}
  {% endblock %}
  {% load  static  wagtailsettings_tags %}
  {% get_settings %}
</head>
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
  {% main_menu max_levels=2 add_sub_menus_inline=True  %}
</body>
</html>
```

***templates/menus/main/menu.html***

```html
{% load menu_tags %}

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-lg"
    role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Title</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler text-white" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-01">
        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-01">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto text-white">
          {% for item in menu_items %}
            {% if item.sub_menu %}
              <li class="nav-item dropdown {{item.active_class}}"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{{ item.href }}" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.text }}</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ item.href }}"><b>{{ item.text }}</b></a>
                {% for sub_item in item.sub_menu.items %}
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ sub_item.href }}">{{ sub_item.text }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </li>
            {% else %}
              <li class="nav-item {{item.active_class}}"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          <li class="nav-link"><a href="/search/"><i class="fas fa-search" title="Search"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

No errors in the console, nothing.  Again, I've triple-checked to ensure my pages are checked with "show in menus".  Where else can I look?  I know for sure the menu itself is loading in because the search icon shows up.

I'm running Django=3.1.2, Wagtail=2.11.3, and WagtailMenus=3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the pages in question and checking whether the “Show in menus” checkbox is checked (found under the “Promote” tab by default).[1](https://github.com/jazzband/wagtailmenus/issues/207)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the closing tags, `</head>, </body>` in your base.html. Have you added them?

Comment: yes you need, for better understand please, read some conventions rules: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks folks.  Yeah, I didn't post my entire base.html because it's way too long, I accidentally clipped out the /head, /body, and /html tags.  They are there in the actual file.  I've updated the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you said you have recreated the database, have you add the pages to Wagtail menu? Wagtail admin > Settings > Main menu?